# Does Google Search Ranking punish websites which use fingerprint tracking?

Tags: google-search, google-ranking

My website uses [flexible sampling](https://developers.google.com/search/docs/advanced/appearance/flexible-sampling) to limit the number of free articles unregistered users can view. I use [fingerprint tracking](https://www.npmjs.com/package/get-browser-fingerprint) to keep track of which customers have reached their monthly view limit. When doing fingerprint tracking, I also check whether the useragent is Googlebot and if it is, I will give it full access to crawl my website.

However, I have seen a few articles (like this [one](https://digiday.com/media/googles-opaque-practices-to-restrict-fingerprinting-create-confusion-among-its-ad-tech-partners/)) saying that Google is against fingerprint tracking. I wonder if I use fingerprint tracking, does Google punish my website's search ranking? If it does, I probably need to switch to cookie tracking.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the articles that I have read(including your mentioned link), Google is against fingerprint tracking for data privacy or advertising purposes. I don't think your customer view limit is data that is prohibited for fingerprinting. So it should not affect Google's search ranking.

As far as I know, most web securities/firewalls like Cloudflare use browser fingerprint to protect against bots, so I think it's similar to your use case.